# problems with a scope in habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, record

I have a habtm relationship between Dish and DailyMenu. Here is a scope

```
  scope :menu_available, -> (type_id, daily_menu_id){ where('dish_type_id = ?', type_id) & where(joins(:daily_menus).where.not('daily_menu_id = ?', daily_menu_id)) }
```

It intends to find dishes of some type but that are not currently included in menu. Sadly it does not work correctly. Need some help please
A DishType model

```
class DishType < ActiveRecord::Base
 include DishTypeSetter
 enum meal:[:main_course, :second_course, :drink]   
end
```

Dish model

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :daily_menus
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
  belongs_to :dish_type 

  scope :main_meals, -> { joins(:dish_type).where('meal = ?', 0) }
  scope :second_meals, -> { joins(:dish_type).where('meal = ?', 1) }
  scope :drinks, -> { joins(:dish_type).where('meal = ?', 2) }

  #scope :menu_available, -> (type_id, daily_menu_id){ where('dish_type_id = ?', type_id) & where(joins(:daily_menus).where.not('daily_menu_id = ?', daily_menu_id)) }


  scope :menu_available, lambda { |type_id, daily_menu_id|
where(joins(:daily_menus).where('daily_menu_id != ? AND dish_type_id = ?', daily_menu_id, type_id))
```

}

```
  validates :dish_type, :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :dish_type_id }

end
```

Menu model

```
class DailyMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes
 has_many :orders
 has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

Also about DishType model - it only has has_many dishes association(I moved this to a concern)/ But it does not have has_many daily_menus/

```
create_table "daily_menus", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "day"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.date     "date"
end

add_index "daily_menus", ["day"], name: "index_daily_menus_on_day", unique: true, using: :btree

create_table "daily_menus_dishes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "daily_menu_id"
  t.integer "dish_id"
end

create_table "dish_types", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "meal"
end

create_table "dishes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "type"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.integer  "dish_type_id"
end  

add_index "dishes", ["dish_type_id", "name"], name: "index_dishes_on_dish_type_id_and_name", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :menu_available, lambda { |type_id, daily_menu_id|        
  joins(:daily_menus)
    .where('dishes.dish_type_id = ? AND daily_menus.id != ?', type_id, daily_menu_id)
}
```

Comment: I looks right but does not workn ( it select all dishes created right now

Comment: @anti-k which table is `daily_menu_id` in?

Comment: Its a seperate table

Comment: @anti-k is it a column in `dishes` table or in `daily_menus` column?

Comment: Its a seperate table :dish_types Updated my question  
end

Comment: @anti-k then you have to use it in query. Edit the question with all models which columns you want to use in this scope.

Comment: belongs_to a dish I updated question with a Dish model

Comment: @anti-k I edited the answer, see how I included `:dish_type` into `joins` and used that table in scope

Comment: Thank a lot but daily menu actually does not have a dish type )) only dish belongs to dishtype. Maybe I should post a schema? Thanks for helping man!b You are saving my night!

Comment: @anti-k so you want: dishes with specific dish_type_id and specific daily_menu_id?

Comment: yes, that's what I whant. I suppose that there should be 2 queries cause we have to join 2 tables? Would pasting my schema help?

Comment: @anti-k `joins(:dish_type).where(dishes: { daily_menu_id: daily_menu_id }, dish_types: { id: type_id })`

Comment: DishType Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "dish_types".* FROM "dish_types" WHERE "dish_types"."meal" = $1  ORDER BY "dish_types"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["meal", 0]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column dishes.daily_menu_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."dish_type_id" WHERE "dish_types"."id" = $1 AND "dishes"."...
Here what I'm receiving

Comment: @anti-k how is then your HABTM is done if there is no foreign_key?

Comment: Ill post my schema for you to look at it

Comment: Updated my schema and checked - habtm works just fine

Comment: @anti-k this is what I do not like about unclear questions - info that keep coming... You have to specify this data from the very beginning.

Comment: SELECT  "dish_types".* FROM "dish_types" WHERE "dish_types"."meal" = $1  ORDER BY "dish_types"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["meal", 0]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column dishes.daily_menu_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."dish_type_id" WHERE "dish_types"."id" = $1 AND "dishes"."...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "dishes".* FROM "dishes" INNER JOIN "dish_types" ON "dish_types"."id" = "dishes"."dish_type_id" WHERE "dish_types"."id" = $1 AND "dishes"."daily_menu_id" = 17

Comment: Im not good at SQl but foreign keys are in daily_menus_dishes table - its habtm?? And you right about unclear question I'll try to be more straightforward

Comment: are you sure you have copypasted it correctly? i did not write `dishes.daily_menu_id` anywhere in the scope

Comment: Yep man! I changed a bit like this scope :menu_available, lambda { |type_id, daily_menu_id|
   joins(:daily_menus).where( dishes: { dish_type_id: type_id }, daily_menus: { id: daily_menu_id } )
  }
Now it works, but finds dishes that are right type but are alread in menu/ I need it reverse about menu. Like dishes that are not in there right now ))

Comment: id sould not be equal to---  id: daily_menu_id . But id != daily_menu_id. How can I change this in that hash?

Comment: Dish.menu_available(DishType.main_course.first.id, 17)
  DishType Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "dish_types".* FROM "dish_types" WHERE "dish_types"."meal" = $1  ORDER BY "dish_types"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["meal", 0]]
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'daily_menus_dishes' was not found on Dish; perhaps you misspelled it? That is about last edit.

Comment: @anti-k here is with `!=`: `scope :menu_available, lambda { |type_id, daily_menu_id|
  joins(:daily_menus).where('dishes.dish_type_id = ? AND daily_menus.id != ?', type_id, daily_menu_id)
}`

Comment: The last return empty array but should not. (( By the way thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I tried like this but it gives all for a special type presence in menu is not considered    scope :menu_available, lambda { |type_id, daily_menu_id| where('dish_type_id = ?', type_id).where( joins(:daily_menus).where('daily_menus.id != ?', daily_menu_id)) }

Comment: Thanks a lot man for helping. Here is my final variant  scope :without_menu, lambda { |type_id, menu_id| joins('LEFT JOIN daily_menus_dishes ON dishes.id = daily_menus_dishes.dish_id').where('daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id is NULL OR daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id != ?', menu_id).where(dish_type: type_id).order('name ASC') } Not cool but working ))

Comment: @anti-k glad you finally made it!